# What's a good life-proof Android phone?

Tags: smartphones, android, durability

I'm quite a clumsy person and so for me phone durability is one the most important aspects for choosing a phone.

Functionally the phone should be a standard high-end phone:

- Decent photos
- Responsive apps
- Reasonably sized (not tiny, doesn't need to be iPhone6/Galaxy Note sized).

Life events it should resist are:

- Dropping on the floor
- Banging the headphone and other cables while they're plugged in.
- Spilling water/drinks on it.

Answer (score 10):

The Samsung Galaxy S6 Active is essentially a rugged version of the Samsung Galaxy 6 with a better battery, so I think that would be well suited to your needs. A review of the S6 Active is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm30TSUY2nI).

If that is above your price range, apparently CAT makes phones now: http://www.catphones.com/ The S50 actually seems like a decent phone at a reasonable price, so you should check that out. Caterpillar created a [promotional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVPku-xItv8) as part of their "BuiltForIt" campaign that featured the phone.

Additionally, you could buy an Otterbox for a common phone and though it would be clunky, it would be able to withstand pretty much anything. I also have heard that Griffin makes very high quality phone cases.

Answer (score 7):

I, and my son, both have Samsung Galaxy S4 Active and its survived all the things you were wondering about. You can get them at a very reasonable price on the worlds largest online vendor but make sure you get one that is compatible with your phone provider. You probably don't need the extra features that come with the S6 and if you manage to destroy a $200 device its a lot less painful then losing $700.

While I still think the S4 Active is a terrific phone and new ones (S4 Active) can be had for $139 on the aforementioned vendor you should make sure that you can still update the OS on the phone. I would look at a later version of the Samsung 'S' Active line because not only is it software update able but the cameras are so, so much better now. Currently I upgraded to a S7 and love it.

Answer (score 4):

The upcoming Moto X Force is the phone that sounds like the perfect fit. It has been announced for release in the US and will be released in other countries starting mid-November.

**Specifications**

- 5.42" QHD screen
- 2GHz 8-core Snapdragon 810 processor
- 3GB RAM
- 64GB of expandable storage
- IP68 certified – dust and water-resistant up to 1.5 meters and 30 minutes
- MIL-STD-810G certified – salt, dust, humidity, rain, vibration, solar radiation, transport and thermal shock resistant
- Corning Gorilla Glass 4
- 21MP main camera and 5MP front-facing camera
- 3760 mAh battery

[Moto X info announcement via engadget.com](http://www.engadget.com/2015/10/29/moto-x-force)

So if you can wait and you're willing to spend around €500 that phone will be great for you!

Comment: Why hasn't anyone mentioned the Droid Turbo 2?

Comment: @RubyJunk moto x force and the droid turbo 2 are both the same

Comment: I wouldn't describe this phone as drop proof with gorilla glass 4.  Maybe with a lifeproof type case but as stated.